# Select lists where last elements are identical

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the following list

```
t1 = {{5, 5, 50}, {6, 1, 37}, {6, 2, 40}, {6, 3, 45}, {7, 4, 65}, {7, 6, 85}, {8, 1, 65}, {6, 6, 72}, {7, 1, 50}};
```

I want to find those triples having the same element in the last position. Which results in

```
{{5, 5, 50}, {7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}, {7, 1, 50}}
```

I can do it by:

```
t2 = Select[Tally[t1[[All, 3]]], Last[#] > 1 &][[All, 1]];
Select[t1, MemberQ[#, Alternatives @@ t2] &]
```

Any ideas for polishing this clumsy code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Preserving the order:

```
With[{c = CountsBy[t1, Last]}, Select[t1, c[Last@#] > 1 &]]
```

Answer (score 8):

If order is not important

```
t1 // GroupBy[Last] // Select[Length[#] > 1 &] // Values

(* {{{5, 5, 50}, {7, 1, 50}}, {{7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
GroupBy[Counts[t1[[All, -1]]]@#[[-1]] > 1 &][t1]@True
```

> ```
>   {{5, 5, 50}, {7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}, {7, 1, 50}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Using `GatherBy` similarly to Rohit's `GroupBy` solution (I even emulate his style because I find it really nice):

```
GatherBy[t1, Last] // Select[Length[#] > 1 &] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> `{{5, 5, 50}, {7, 1, 50}, {7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}}`

To add a bit more novelty to the answer, I also submit these rule based solutions:

```
ReplaceList[
 SortBy[t1, Last],
 {___, l : Repeated[{_, _, x_}, {2, Infinity}], ___} :> l
 ]
```

> `{{5, 5, 50}, {7, 1, 50}, {7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}}`

```
SequenceCases[
  SortBy[t1, Last],
  {Repeated[{_, _, x_}, {2, Infinity}]}
  ] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> `{{5, 5, 50}, {7, 1, 50}, {7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}}`

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

Acting on the advice given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225010/106):

```
Pick[#1,Replace[#1[[All,#2]],Unitize[Counts[#1[[All,#2]]]-1],{1}],1]&@@{t1,-1}
```

---

**Original Answer**

```
Pick[#1,#1[[All,#2]]/.Unitize[Counts[#1[[All,#2]]]-1],1]&@@{t1,-1}
```

> {{5, 5, 50}, {7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}, {7, 1, 50}}

For identities at position 2 (if desired):

```
Pick[#1,#1[[All,#2]]/.Unitize[Counts[#1[[All,#2]]]-1],1]&@@{t1,2}
```

> {{6, 1, 37}, {7, 6, 85}, {8, 1, 65}, {6, 6, 72}, {7, 1, 50}}

Answer (score 1):

Via `PositionIndex`

```
t1[[Flatten @ Cases[{_, _}] @ PositionIndex[Last /@ t1]]]
```

{{5, 5, 50}, {7, 1, 50}, {7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}}

If order is important we sort the positions:

```
t1[[Sort @ Flatten @ Cases[{_, _}] @ PositionIndex[Last /@ t1]]]
```

{{5, 5, 50}, {7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}, {7, 1, 50}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Subsets` and `Select`:

```
t1 = {{5, 5, 50}, {6, 1, 37}, {6, 2, 40}, {6, 3, 45}, {7, 4, 65},
      {7, 6, 85}, {8, 1, 65}, {6, 6, 72}, {7, 1, 50}};

Select[Subsets[t1, {2}], #[[1, 3]] == #[[2, 3]] &]

(*{{{5, 5, 50}, {7, 1, 50}}, {{7, 4, 65}, {8, 1, 65}}}*)
```