# How to NOT a specific pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching

been going around in cirlces on this:

`{1/3, 1, 0.22, 3, "v", 4} /. _?NumericQ -> "999"`

Now I'm trying to replace everything that is **not** a number; is there a way to do this? using `Not` or `Except` perhaps...I've tried but I must be getting the syntax wrong!

Comment: [Strongly related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35261/how-do-i-define-an-argument-pattern-for-a-head-of-not-a-given-value)

Answer (score 13):

If you are going to replace elements of a list, do not use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html). Use [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), which is the appropriate function for that task.

```
Replace[list, Except[_?NumericQ] :> "non-numeric", {1}]
```

The 3rd argument, `{1}`, indicates that only elements of the list ("1st level") are to be replaced, not the list itself.

If you were to use `ReplaceAll`, it would replace *the entire list*, as it does not match `_?NumericQ`. An over-use of `ReplaceAll` out of convenience (`/.` shorthand) or lack of awareness causes a lot of bugs in Mathematica code. I strongly suggest sticking to `Replace` unless you know you need `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: Good answer. To understand a bit more, try replacing Except by Identity in the above to see the difference. The trick here, for me at least, is understanding where to put the Blank (i.e the _).

Answer (score 7):

By 1) Using `Replace` with a level spec so we don't replace the whole list but the elements, and 2) using a `Composition` (short form `@*`) of `Not` with `NumericQ`:

```
Replace[{1/3, 1, 0.22, 3, "v", 4}, _?(Not@*NumericQ) -> "999", {1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not new answer, just pulls together many of the responses in a consistent format, showing the experiments tried.

```
p1 = _?( Not @* NumericQ);

p2 = _? (Not @ NumericQ[#] &);

p3 = Except[_?NumericQ];

p4 = Except[x_ /; NumericQ[x]];

Replace[lis, p1 -> "999", {1}]

    {1/3, 1, 0.22, 3, "999", 4}

Replace[lis, p2 -> "999", {1}]

    {1/3, 1, 0.22, 3, "999", 4}

Replace[lis, p3 -> "999", {1}]

    {1/3, 1, 0.22, 3, "999", 4}

Replace[lis, p4 -> "999", {1}]

   {1/3, 1, 0.22, 3, "999", 4}
```